# How to check which files are changed in magento 2 patch?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I applied this magento 2 patch: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-18/acsd-46146-two-order-confirmation-emails-are-sent-after-placing-order-from-admin.html?lang=en

How can I check what exactly is changed in that patch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command to check the changed files in the M2 patch:

git apply --stat <patch_file_path>

Change <patch_file_path> with the actual path to your patch file. it will display the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the patch list here https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/tree/master/patches/os

Hope this can help